# invisible items in Horizontal recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using GridLayoutManager to show some image in recyclerview with HORIZONTAL orientation.
But images are invisible in recyclerview. when i tap in the empty space it shows the image in another activity but they are invisible in the recyclerview. i have tried VERTICAL and they are prefectly fine and visible.

here is my fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/page_start" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.java :

```
RecyclerView rv;
    List<Cards> cardsList;
    Context context;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container, false);

        readJson readJson = new readJson(context);
        cardsList = readJson.getcardsList();

        rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        rv.setAdapter(new CardsListAdapter(empty, context));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));"
```

use below line

```
rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

or

```
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

Comment: they are invisible too!